# Is it possible to use multiple LUIS application in single bot services?

Tags: node.js, chatbot, azure-language-understanding, azure-bot-service

I have a Azure Bot Service and it is integrated with LUIS application where i have some intents.
What I want according to my need i can forward same examples to different intents in LUIS.

But there is limitation that same example can't be there for multiple intents.
So i created another application in the LUIS and created the same example but different intent name.
Here my problem is i have to connect Single Bot service with two different LUIS application.
Can i do it in Azure Bot Services in Node.js??

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it is absolutely possible to make use of multiple LUIS applications in one bot. The dispatch tool helps to determine which LUIS model best matches the user input. **The dispatch tool does this by creating a single LUIS app to route user input to the correct model.** Also, **ensure that you do not have overlapping intents** and make use of prediction data from LUIS to determine if your intents are overlapping.

The dispatch model is used in cases when:

- Your bot consists of multiple modules and you need assistance in routing user's utterances to these modules and evaluate the bot integration.
- Evaluate the quality of intents classification of a single LUIS model.
- Create a text classification model from text files.

Refer to this [sample](https://github.com/Microsoft/BotBuilder-Samples/tree/master/samples/javascript_nodejs/14.nlp-with-dispatch), which is an NLP with Dispatch bot dealing with multiple LUIS models and also this [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/bot-service/bot-builder-tutorial-dispatch?view=azure-bot-service-4.0&tabs=cs) that provides more information about using multiple LUIS and QnAMaker models.

Hope this helps!!

Comment: If you found the answer helpful, can you upvote and accept it so that it helps others as well? Thanks